# Error having two columns in primarykey when using computed colum (EF Migrations)

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add migrations for a model which has multiple versions of my model in time (ModificationDate).

Creating a PK based on Id alone creates the migrations without incident (also tried ModificationDate as PK also no problems). But when I use `Id` + `ModificationDate` to create a PK I'm getting the following error:

> The property 'Id' cannot be configured as 'ValueGeneratedOnUpdate' or
> 'ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate' because the key value cannot be changed
> after the entity has been added to the store.

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTimeOffset ModificationDate { get; set; }
    public string Json { get; set; }
}

protected override CreateModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>()
        .ToTable("model")
        .HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.ModificationDate });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>()
        .Property(t => t.Id)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("CAST(JSON_Value(Json, '$.Id') as int) PERSISTED");
}
```

I'm using EF Core Tools version 3.1.13.

---

**Update**

No fix but I fill the Id manually instead taking it from the json value.

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTimeOffset ModificationDate { get; set; }
    public string Json { get; set; }
}

protected override CreateModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Model>()
        .ToTable("model")
        .HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.ModificationDate });
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but you really have a very strange primary key. What answer are you expecting - to remove datetime or remove id or change id to string?

Comment: Using two values to create a PK isn’t uncommon. I’m looking for a way to accomplish this without the error or an explanation on why this isn’t possible.

Comment: You already get an error from compiler with the explanation why it is not possible.  Now you have to make some changes in the model. This is why I asked you what do you prefer. But I don't think that you need my answer and post the question for this. You are able to decide it yourself

Comment: Yes I did get an error which don't make sense to me, hence the question :D